# What is the algorithm for the cost of religious units?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 6, the cost of religious units seems to go up the more you build. For example my first inquisitor was 100 faith, and the next one will be 105 faith. The same happens for missionaries and apostles, but I haven't kept close enough track to see what the algorithm is.

It also seems like the cost might go up over time or based on other factors. The base cost of an inquisitor is 50, but as I said my cost was 100.

Comment: Any chance you've had two cities at that time? Haven't had a too close look at costs, but they should scale with the number of cities I think.

Comment: I've had the same number of cities at all times.

Comment: The same question goes for gold purchases too, they go up the more you buy the same things, but I don't know the formula

Answer (score -1):

That's a very general concept in Civ 6 - the cost of everything grows with the number of previously built (including bought) things. Not just for units and not just for religion.

Some people plan to start building some districts early and then switch to another they actually need at the time since that fixes the cost. Can't use that trick with buying since that is instantaneous transaction.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't noticed a change in cost based on anything but how many of the unit you've purchased before.  I haven't purchased many Inquisitors, but Missionaries seemed to be 50, +5 each time you purchase one, and Apostles are 150 (I think), +5 each time you purchase one.

As a side note, what civilization were you playing?  I seem to remember some of them having effects that could modify your price (as well as some wonders).

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, but I would agree that each unit cost 5 faith more than the previous.

Of course, if you're Teocracy or have selected other bonus with a discount on faith, the cost will increase less.
For Example, if you have a total discount of -20% on faith (don't even know if it's possible to reach this exact number) each unit will cost you (20% * 5 =) 4 faith more than the previous.

Oh, of course the cost depend on the speed: if you're playng "Online Speed" the cost less for everything, not only faith, but even gold culture production science....

So this "+5" that I noticed is bound to a specific game speed, could be the normal speed, could be the online speed. I will check out soon